# Is this a 3NF violation?

Tags: database, database-design

I want to create a database with counties + lakes and rivers located within them. Is this a 3NF violation if I have a table "lakes" with following attributes:

- id (PK)
- name
- area
- depth

or perhaps "area" and "depth" should be in another table like "measurements" connected by the foreign key?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question? What would happened if you bound two lakes to the same measurement and a dam burst on one of the lakes, how do you account for the increase in size without affecting the other lake?

Comment: Never mind, I think I read that wrong. Are you are asking about creating a table to hold metadata about the lake and refer to the metadata table using the lakes' id?

Comment: Exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3rd normal form is a little different. 3NF would apply to a table where you wanted to record historical lake levels.

**LakeLevel**

- id (PK)
- name
- area
- depth
- Year

If you did not include the year then the **Lake** table would be in 3NF because all attributes pertain directly to the entity the PK in drawn against. When you add year, the area/depth and I guess name too, could describe both the lake and the attributes pertaining to another entity, the year. The LakeLevel table could be taken to the 3NF by breaking it up one more time.